# Accessing JSONB element by a variable path

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, jsonb

I need to join two json values into one.
But the location of these variables is dynamic, I get the locations in the jsonb from a database.

So I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
select '{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb #> '{"a","b","c"}';
```

But I cannot get it to work with variables as I do not know what to cast the path to.

```
select '{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb #> ('{"a","' || variable_from_database || '","c"}')::dataTypeOfJsonbPath;
```

I also found that I can use a query like this:

```
select value#>>'{"c"}' from jsonb_each(('{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb#>'{"a"}')) where key = 'b';
```

That would solve the problem of fetching the values, but now I need to concat them in the original jsonb value and I am currently out of ideas of how to get that done.

```
jsonb_set('{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb, ('{"a","' || value2FromDatabase || '", "c"}'),
                                          (value1 || value2)::jsonb, false);
```

The above fails for the same reason.

Listing the required parameters for jsonb_set tells me that the 2nd parameter should be of type ARRAY, but I don't know how to cast that string to an array that will make this work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to append one value to another within a jsonb object where the keys of both are on dynamic locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your path into type `text[]`

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=333b20e3b9e28e3b63f981da3e7a4efa)

```
SELECT
    '{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb #> ('{"a","' || path || '","c"}')::text[]
FROM 
    mytable
```

Comment: I believe that you're the most prominent expert for `[postgresql]+[json(b)]` combination :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
select '{"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}'::jsonb #>> ('{"a","'||'b'||'","c"}')::text[];
```

That works, so I need to cast to text[].
That works!